# How to get files names with specific extension from a folder in perl

Tags: perl, search, glob

Currently in a perl script I am using the `glob` function to get a list of files with specific extensions.

```
my @filearray = glob("$DIR/*.abc $DIR/*.llc");
```

Is there any alternative to glob, to get the list of files with specific extension from a folder? If so please provide me some example? Thank you

Comment: Why is `glob` not good enough?

Comment: You could use a regex.

Comment: glob is failing sometimes with lower versions of perl runtime.

Comment: What are "lower versions of perl runtime"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are much more complicated ways, like `opendir`, `readdir` and a regex filter. They will also give you the hidden files (or dotfiles):

```
opendir DIR, $DIR or die $!;
my @filearray = grep { /\.(abc|llc)$/ } readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;
```

Comment: I am running the perl script in windows environment. the above code is not working from the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Using:
opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "$!";
my @files = grep(/\.[abc|lic]*$/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

#Reference: CPAN
use Path::Class;  # Exports dir() by default

my $dir = dir('foo', 'bar');       # Path::Class::Dir object
my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new('foo', 'bar');  # Same thing

my $file = $dir->file('file.txt'); # A file in this directory
my $handle = $dir->open;
while (my $file = $handle->read)
{
    $file = $dir->file($file);  # Turn into Path::Class::File object
    ...
}

#Reference: Refered: http://accad.osu.edu/~mlewis/Class/Perl/perl.html#cd
# search for a file in all subdirectories
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
if ($#ARGV != 0) {
    print "usage: findfile filename\n";
    exit;
}

$filename = $ARGV[0];

# look in current directory
$dir = getcwd();
chop($dir);
&searchDirectory($dir);

sub searchDirectory
{
    local($dir);
    local(@lines);
    local($line);
    local($file);
    local($subdir);

    $dir = $_[0];

    # check for permission
    if(-x $dir)
{
    # search this directory
    @lines = `cd $dir; ls -l | grep $filename`;
    foreach $line (@lines)
    {
        $line =~ /\s+(\S+)$/;
        $file = $1;
        print "Found $file in $dir\n";
    }
    # search any sub directories
    @lines = `cd $dir; ls -l`;
    foreach $line (@lines)
    {
        if($line =~ /^d/)
        {
            $line =~ /\s+(\S+)$/;
            $subdir = $dir."/".$1;
            &searchDirectory($subdir);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Please try another one:

```
use Cwd;
use File::Find;
my $dir = getcwd();
my @abclicfiles;

find(\&wanted, $dir);
sub wanted
{
    push(@abclicfiles, $File::Find::name) if($File::Find::name=~m/\.(abc|lic)$/i);
}
print join "\n", @abclicfiles;
```

This the directory which is getting from user:

```
print "Please enter the directory: ";
my $dir = <STDIN>;
chomp($dir);

opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Couldn't able to read dir: $!";
my @files = grep(/\.(txt|lic)$/, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);
print join "\n", @files;
```

Comment: I am running the perl script in windows environment. the above code is not working from the script.

Comment: Thank you it is working. It is retrieving files in the subfolders also. How could we make this to retrieve the files in only main folder which we have pased?